# GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() is not returning

Tags: android, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In my Android application, I am trying to get Google token to connect to Google Spreadsheets. This is the code that does that:

```
AsyncTask<String, Void, String> getTokenTask = new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.i("Groceryviewer", "doInBackground() - Entry");
        String accountName = params[0];
        String token = null;
        try {
            Log.i("Groceryviewer", "Before get token");
            token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(LoginHomeActivity.this, accountName, "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://docs.google.com/feeds");
            Log.i("Groceryviewer", "After get token. Token: " + token);
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            Log.e("Groceryviewer", "Exception in getToken() - UserRecoverableAuthException", e);
            Log.i("Groceryviewer", "Exception in getToken() - startActivityForResult");
            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), USER_ACCEPTS);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Groceryviewer", "Exception in getToken() - IOException", e);
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            Log.e("Groceryviewer", "Exception in getToken() - GoogleAuthException", e);
        }
        Log.i("Groceryviewer", "doInBackground() - Exit");
        return token;
    }

};
getTokenTask.execute(accountName);

String token = null;
try {
    token = getTokenTask.get();
} catch(ExecutionException e) {
    Log.i("Groceryviewer", "Exception in get() - ExecutionException", e);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Log.i("Groceryviewer", "Exception in get() - InterruptedException", e);
}
Log.i("Groceryviewer", "Token: " + token);
```

I have added this to AndroidManifest.xml as well:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

The problem is that getToken does not return at all.  Here are my logs:

```
01-01 17:28:57.583: I/Groceryviewer(1485): doInBackground() - Entry
01-01 17:28:57.583: I/Groceryviewer(1485): Before get token
```

Can someone help me figure out why this error is happening?

Comment: I used the google DrEdit tutorial to get this to work (OAuth2). I searched for a long time to find something better, but the "DrEdit" was the best I could find, (I use AppEngine not android).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the scope:

> There’s really only one method call you need to use,
>   GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(). It takes three arguments: a Context, an
>   email address, and another string argument called scope.

```
 private final static String G_SPREADSHEET_SCOPE = 
  "oauth2:https://docs.google.com/feeds/ https://docs.googleusercontent.com/ https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/";
```

http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/google-play-services-and-oauth-identity.html

Comment: You are right. The scope you had given is for Google Plus APIs (as mentioned in the link you have given). The scope I should have used is this `https://docs.google.com/feeds/ https://docs.googleusercontent.com/ https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/` This is the link from where I got that: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#authorizing_requests_with_oauth_20

Comment: Google says you need to migrate from GoogleAuthUtil and Plus.API https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/migration-guide